# Htaccess Rewrite Condition Issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to follow Paul Irish's example of how to have a built minified version of my site inside `/publish`. I have successfully integrated the automated build process but can't get the .htaccess file to point to the correct folder.

**My Aim:**

When on live server to redirect all normal site traffic to the `/publish` folder to use the 'built' site. But when on the development server to use the development files in the `/` normal root folder.

**My Problem:**

I want the htaccess to rewrite requests from the root to the `/publish` directory. As the same htaccess be will used inside the `/` and `/publish` directory I need a rewrite condition to stop it rewriting requests inside the `/publish` directory to `/publish/publish/my-page`. I have this at present:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !^/publish/.+
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ publish/$1 [L]
```

The condition above  looks for requests that do not have the `script_filename` starting with `/publish`. If so it should rewrite the request with `publish/` in front.

However, this is not working. Does anyone have any ideas what is wrong with it? Could I use different server variables to identify if the request is in the `/publish` directory or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead as it is the correct variable that will have path relative to the site root and not physical file name like others.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/publish/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ publish/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think `%{SCRIPT_FILENAME}` isn't set when you don't explicitely ask Apache a php file, maybe you should try with `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` instead.
By the way, you can have a look on mod_rewrite doc page for more informations : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond